# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with HBase Scan

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, hbase

I am trying to run a MapReduce job to scan a HBase table. Currently I am using the version 0.94.6 of HBase that comes with Cloudera 4.4. At some point in my program I use Scan(), and I properly import it with:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
```

It compiles well and I am able to create a jar file too. I do it by passing the `hbase classpath` as the value for the -cp option. When running the program, I obtain the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan
```

I run the code using:

```
hadoop jar my_program.jar MyJobClass -libjars <list_of_jars>
```

where list_of_jars contains /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/hbase.jar. Just to double-check, I confirmed that hbase.jar contains Scan. I do it with:

```
jar tf /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/hbase.jar
```

And I can see the line:

```
org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.class
```

in the output. All looks ok to me. I don't understand why is saying that Scan is not defined. I pass the correct jar, and it contains the class.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the HADOOP_CLASSPATH variable fixed the issue:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`/usr/bin/hbase classpath`
```

Comment: In which file do I need to set the above said classpath?

Comment: change in the ~/.bash_profile  `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`depend_on_you_machine/bin/hbase classpath

Comment: and in linux? We need to add this in bashrc or hbase-env.sh file?