# NoClassDefFoundError HBase with YARN

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hadoop-yarn

I know that this is one of the topic that's asked much. Still after I digged into all of the topics I could find (most of them talking about CLASSPATH), I cant solve mine.

Examples of the topics I found and tried:

[Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364057/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-hadoop-hba)

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with HBase Scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577680/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-with-hbase-scan)

I'm using Hadoop 2.5.1 with HBase 0.98.11 on Ubuntu 14.04

I set up pseudo-distributed mode and running hadoop with hbase successfully. After I want to set up the full-distributed mode, jobs fail with NoClassDefFound error. I tried adding "export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`/usr/local/hbase-0.98.11-hadoop2/bin/hbase classpath`" into hadoop-env (also yarn-env), still dont work.

One notice I found is if I comment the

```
<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>
```

I can run the jobs SUCCESSFULLY. BUT it seems that I run it on single not multi node.

Here are some of the configs:

mapred-site

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>hadoop1:54311</value>
  <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
  at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
  and reduce task.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>`
```

hdfs-site

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>2</value>
  <description>Default block replication.
  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
  </description>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.use.datanode.hostname</name>
   <value>false</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check</name>
   <value>false</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.permissions</name>
   <value>false</value>
 </property>
```

yarn-site

```
     <property>
         <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
         <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
         <description>shuffle service that needs to be set for Map Reduce to run 
 </description>
     </property>

     <property>
         <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
         <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
     </property>
```

In yarn-env and hadoop-env there is just as default except the HADOOP_CLASSPATH (which doesn't change things even if I add it or not..)

Here is the error trace:

> 2015-04-25 23:29:25,143 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
>       at apriori2$FrequentItemsReduce.reduce(apriori2.java:550)
>       at apriori2$FrequentItemsReduce.reduce(apriori2.java:532)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$NewCombinerRunner.combine(Task.java:1651)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.sortAndSpill(MapTask.java:1611)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.flush(MapTask.java:1462)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:700)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.closeQuietly(MapTask.java:1990)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:774)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)

Really thanks for every help sir.

Answer (score 0):

With Yarn, you need to set "**yarn.application.classpath**" property with the classpath for your MapReduce job. "export HADOOP_CLASSPATH" would not work with Yarn.

Comment: I tried setting yarn.application.classpath with value of so many paths (in Hadoop and HBase). After running the job, the exit code(1)'s thrown.

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace? You need make sure all the directories are present in values of "yarn.application.classpath"

Comment: which file we need to set "yarn.application.classpath" ??

Comment: You can add it in yarn-site.xml or you can specify this property while submitting the job with -Dyarn.application.classpath option.